# Is there a way to properly anchor an imageview in a CollapsingToolBarLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to put an ImageView at the bottom of a collapsing tool bar

I tried replacing the FloatingActionButton that was there by default with an ImageView and the following was the result

[ImageView in place of FloatingActionButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnHC8.png)

It looks good at first but when I scroll up this happens

[ImageView when scrolling up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEtKY.png)

The ImageView does not disappear or collapse like it does with the FloatingActionButton.

What do I do to make the ImageView disappear when scrolling up?

Here is my layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.kid.uimockup.UserProfileActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/white"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:minHeight="100dp"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_user_profile"/>

   //I want to anchor this
  <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
      android:layout_width="100dp"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:layout_margin="7dp"
      android:src="@drawable/breaking_bad"
      app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
      app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"/>

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @Zaki just edited in the layout code

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a custom implementation of a [CoordinatorLayout.Behavior](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.Behavior.html).

I made a quick implementation based off the `FloatingActionButton` implementation for showing/hiding when anchored to an `AppBarLayout`. You can see the code for that [here](https://gist.github.com/alex-townsend/e4cda67be7a42540834b). Please note the package name -- you need to have this in that package to make use of some of the util methods in the `Behavior`.

To add the `Behavior` to your `CircleImageView` you do the following:

```
// your image view here
CircleImageView imageView = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.circle_image_view);

CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params =
    (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
params.setBehavior(new CircleImageViewBehavior());
```

Now when you scroll far enough up/down the `CircleImageView` should be displayed or hidden. If you want the animation like `FloatingActionButton` uses, you can look in to that implementation to create a similar animation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not sure if this is a stupid question but where exactly is android.support.design.widget package?

Comment: You would create the package and file from the gist yourself in your `src/main/java` folder of your project. So the path to it would be `src/main/java/android/support/design/widget/CircleImageViewBehavior.java`.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
```

of `Coordinatorlayout` to

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
```